# AND vs OR operator for finding out if value is within range

Tags: java, operators

I was using Java to write a simple program with range conditioning, and found the below code seem to be inclusive of the floor & ceiling.

i.e. {do something} will be executed even if value equals 1,000 or 1,000,000.

```
if (value < 1000 || value > 1_000_000)
    do something;
```

I know that best practice for finding if value is within/out of range would be to use an && operator instead of ||

```
if (value >= 1000 && value <= 1_000_000)
    do something;
```

But I Just wonder why there would be a difference?

Comment: What difference do you mean?

Comment: [De'morgan's law states that `(!A)&&(!B)` is the same as `!(A||B)` and the other way round.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: re *{do something} will be executed even if value equals 1,000 or 1,000,000.*  -- this **cannot** be the case for the code as written in the first example. The value 1000 is not less than 1000 and it is not greater than 10000000.  The value 1000000 is not less than 1000 and it is not greater than 1000000.   The 'if' condition does not result in 'true' for either of those values.

Answer (score 0):

Your first snippet will the do thing if the value is **not** between one thousand and one million. You've confused yourself there.

The second snippet will the do thing if the value **is** between one thousand and one million.

> I know that best practice for finding if value is within/out of range would be to use an && operator instead of ||

You've been misinformed. There's no such 'best practice'.

When you're making a convoluted mix of AND and OR operations, and some application of De Morgan's law (`!A&&!B` is the same as `!(A||B)`) lets you both remove parentheses and have less switching of operators, that's a good idea, but the best practice there is not 'use && instead of ||' - the best practice is simply 'write code that is easy to read and difficult to misinterpret', and presumably `if (A && !B && C)` is easier to follow along, easier to expand upon, and harder to misunderstand than `if (A && !(B || !C))`, even though they mean the **exact** same thing.

Insofar that whomever told you that the second snippet is somehow best practice actually has a more in-depth idea that does make sense, well, 'why?' - I just told you why. Any best practice is oversimplified and exists as a rule of thumb. You can border any best practice with the following words for it to make sense:

When evaluating any best practice 'X', i.e. instead of 'Use && instead of ||', hang this around X and *then* evaluate it:

"In most applications, applying the rule of 'X' leads to code that is more flexible in the face of changing requests and refactors of code that surrounds it, is easier to understand for your average java programmer (as in, your average coder will probably not read it, think they know what it does, but be mistaken), and is easy to test".

Then plug X back in. If it sounds like horseshit, then that's because it is, and the rule of thumb should not be applied. Even (especially!) if it is a 'commonly accepted best practice'.

Answer (score 0):

you say that this : if (value < 1000 || value > 1_000_000)
do something; will be done if value equals 1000 or 1000000 but in this case it will be done if the value is smaller than 1000 or bigger than 1000000 so you can do:

if (value == 1000 || value == 1_000_000)
do something;

But to your question its a big difference between both of your conzepts so you must know || will be done if one of both is true and && will be done if both are true so its a huge diffrence.